# Subsetting in R , for and if loop

Tags: r, loops, duplicates, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID         Team
11            1
22            2
45            4
45            2
79            3
79            4
100           2
123           1
167           3
167           1
```

I have to subset only those rows which ARE duplicated until the end of the data frame is reached. How can it be done?

Comment: So, by "rows" which are duplicated, you just mean duplicated IDs? The "correct' subset here would be rows 3-6 and 9-10?

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to subset rows that have duplicated `ID`s

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(11L, 22L, 45L, 45L, 79L, 79L, 100L, 123L, 
167L, 167L), Team = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Team"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

dat[duplicated(dat$ID)|duplicated(dat$ID,fromLast=T),]
#     ID Team
# 3   45    4
# 4   45    2
# 5   79    3
# 6   79    4
# 9  167    3
# 10 167    1
```

Comment: The data frame i get with this is emptyI have to print both the copies of the duplicated row

Comment: @user3867198.  Please check if you are still getting empty dataframe by copying the code above.

Comment: Yes. I have to subset the row with duplicated ID.

Comment: @user3867198. I subset it by duplicated ID

Comment: @akrun.I have a table with 1200 values. I cant put them in individual variables. can it be done using a for and if statement?

Comment: @user3867198.  Sorry, I am not following you.  You showed an example that mimics your original dataset, right?  So, if you have 1200 rows or not, this should work.

Comment: @user3867198.  Could you just update your question with more info and data that mimics your original dataset?